# Golang initialize array from variables

Tags: go

I want to initialize an array from variables received as function parameters.

```
func life(rows int, cols int, some float64, generations int){
    var now [rows*cols]int
    now[0] = 1
}
```

I get following error:

> non-constant array bound rows * cols

Is it even possible to achieve something like this with Go? I didn't find any example while Googling. I am starting to learn Go just as I post for college homework.

Comment: Use a slice instead: make([]int,rows*cols).

Comment: now := make([]int, rows*columns)

Comment: In go, don't confuse arrays with slices. Given the requirements, you need the latter.

Comment: You also should consider `make([]int, 0, rows*columns)` because when you do `append()` you increase size and let's say you start with 10 and after append it will be 11 with 10x `0` values. Of course if you do `now[0] = 1` that's ok. Just a tip to remember

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes agree with the comments, just use slice instead of array.
Read [this](https://blog.golang.org/slices) documentation for more detail.

Let me elaborate into full modified function as follow:

```
func life(rows int, cols int, some float64, generations int){
    now := make([]int, rows*cols)
    now[0] = 1
}
```